# Android 11 - setting RNCallkeep.setCurrentCallActive(uuid) causes the native call state to update in self Managed mode, but it should not

Tags: react-native, telephonymanager, telecommunication, android-phone-call, voip-android

Android 11 - setting RNCallkeep.setCurrentCallActive(uuid) causes the native call state to update in self Managed mode, but it should not

I am using [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep)
library to handle my VOIP calls and GSM calls interoperability in my react native application.

Have followed this [installation and setup guide](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/blob/master/docs/android-installation.md#android-common-step-installation) for RNCallkeep and some chunks of this [example](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep/tree/master/example) for the implementation.

Also using [react-native-call-detection](https://github.com/priteshrnandgaonkar/react-native-call-detection) for getting the native call states, to do some action on existing VOIP calls in case of native call interruptions.

However, in Android 11, setting RNCallkeep.setCurrentCallActive(uuid) causes the native call state to update in self Managed "true" mode, but it should not.

Library versions used:

"react-native-call-keep": "4.3.1"
"react-native-call-detection": "1.9.0",
"react-native": "0.62.3"
"sip.js": "0.20.0
Android: 11